# What kind of C++ template programming can be called "meta programming"?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, traits

1. Using what kind of template technical, could be called "meta programming"?
2. Is there a good definition of what's and what's NOT meta programming?
3. Does our C++11 STL contain a lot of meta programming?
4. Is "type_traits" meta programming"?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: logically, "metaprogramming" means programs "about" other programs or "code which generates other code". C preprocessor may be "metaprogramming" also by this definition. I consider type traits to be meta programming. But, this is an english question, not a programming question :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about programming

Comment: @ChrisBeck of course, it is a question about metaprogramming not programming.  :p

Comment: Is programming terminology not about programming? The term "meta" is self-referential. I suppose it means something like "programming the program". It refers to the way templates are not directly (traditional) program code but that they are *instantiated* to become program code. The process rules of *instantiation* are themselves considered a rudimentary (functional) programming language. So, I suppose, as we are using a programming language to create program language it is termed "meta programming".

Comment: @Galik: I think metaprogramming is not actually a technical term, that's why I voted to close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Metaprogramming" is used in informal speech to refer to a variety of programming techniques:

- Information about types, i.e "type traits". This is the most straight forward type of meta, in that "meta" here means "about something"
- (Ab)using the C preprocessor or templates. You are not really programming "in" C++ but rather a sublanguage. The [IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/winners.html) has plenty of examples of people using the C preprocessor to do various complete programs, like Towers of Hanoi and calculating prime numbers. The "classic" example of a template metaprogram is calculating fibonacci. In other words you are going "outside" the normal scope of C++ to create programs, which makes this usage similar to metagaming
- Quines, creating programs that make programs that make programs, self-hosting compilers, etc. Here "meta" means "self-referential", like a fractal

Whether the standard library contains "metaprogramming" is implementation-defined. Some implementations go crazy with it, others don't.

There isn't really a good definition either, the word "meta" is ironically kind of fuzzy.

Answer (score 3):

**Q1.** Using what kind of template technical, could be called "meta programming"?

Template metaprogramming refers to use of templates and the compiler to perform some of the key elements of programming: Looping, if-else branching, C/C++ switch like branching, recursion, etc.

The first such meta program was used to generate the first few prime numbers as compiler error messages. See http://www.erwin-unruh.de/primorig.html

**Q2.** Is there a good definition of what's and what's NOT meta programming?

A good definition can be found at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming).

> Template metaprogramming (TMP) is a metaprogramming technique in which templates are used by a compiler to generate temporary source code, which is merged by the compiler with the rest of the source code and then compiled. The output of these templates include compile-time constants, data structures, and complete functions. The use of templates can be thought of as compile-time execution. The technique is used by a number of languages, the best-known being C++, but also Curl, D, and XL.

**Q3.** Does our C++11 STL contain a lot of meta programming?

Most likely but that's a guess. I haven't delved into any implementation of the standard library.

**Q4.** Is "type_traits" meta programming"?

Once again, I haven't delved into it but I imagine most of the functionality of "type_traits" is implemented using metaprogramming techniques.